# unexpected error on printing string

Tags: c, string, pointers

Why does this code produce an error? Shouldn't it output zbcde?

```
int main()
{
char *p="abcde";
*p='z';
printf("%s\n",p);
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You're trying to modify a string literal; it's undefined behavior.

Further explanation: "abcde" is not a `char *` but a `const char *`. You should do one of the following solutions:

```
char p[] = "abcde";
```

or

```
char *p = strdup("abcde");
```

(in the latter case, don't  forget to free() p!)

Answer (score 2):

`char *p="abcde";` - This will keep the string `abcde` in text segement as read only data and the address will be kept in the local pointer variable `p`.

`*p = 'z'` will tries to replace the read only data `a` to `z`. Which is an undefined behaviour, which can leads to crash.

So declare the string as local char array variable as below.

```
char p[] = "abcde"
```

So allocate dynamic memory to keep the string like below.

```
char *p = strdup("abcde");
...
free(p);
```